# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ".": syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm creating my own query-builder for practice and ran across the following problem; When invoking the `prepare()` method on a `PDO` object with the following query:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`name` = :usersName WHERE `id` = :id;
```

I receive the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ".": syntax error in ....

I've tried this exact same SQL statement in MySQL workbench and PhpMyAdmin, both of these don't return any errors or warnings.

The reason I'm prefixing the table name is because I'm adding up SQL `JOIN`s later on.

Without the table prefix, it works perfectly. Without it, it looks like this:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `name` = :usersName WHERE `id` = :id;
```

My PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php
    $statement = "UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`name` = :usersName WHERE `id` = :id;";

    $PDO = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $PDO->exec("CREATE TABLE users (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50))");
    $PDO->exec("INSERT INTO `users` (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Bas')");
    $PDO->exec("INSERT INTO `users` (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Basert')");

    $statement = $PDO->prepare($statement);
```

The error occurs after that line.

Why does this syntax error occur and how can I fix it without removing the table prefix?

Comment: How are you executing this query? That might be the source of the problem. Also if you're using PDO then it's not necessary to have `;` at the end of your query.

Comment: having tablename prefix in `set` isn't a standard SQL

Comment: @tadman I'm not, just preparing to add parameters later, on that function it already gave the exception.

Comment: @Rahul What do you mean? It did work in the mysql workbench right?

Comment: It's possible that those tools are altering some sort of connection-level setting that you're not doing with PDO. There's a whole bunch of [connection and server level settings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok `new PDO('sqlite::memory:')` : SQLite is not MySQL.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm

The syntax is :

> UPDATE table_name
>
> SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
>
> WHERE [condition];

---

I can't reproduce.
This mean it's probably something from your config or a typo in your query.

Can you past us the code straight from your .php file ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce62724/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(5))
;
    
INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'test'),
    (2, 'test2')
;
UPDATE `users` SET `users`.`name` = 'plop' WHERE `id` = 1;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from `users`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce62724/1/0)**:

```
| id |  name |
|----|-------|
|  1 |  plop |
|  2 | test2 |
```

Comment: I updated my question, when pasting the query in that SQL fiddle I also can't reproduce it when replacing the parameter names with actual values.

Comment: @Bas found it : your using sqlite, not mysql.